# Disable touchpad in Linux

Tags: linux, touchpad, xinput

I want to disable permanently my touchpad when my Debian-based Linux boots up. Every time it boots up, I disable it with `xinput —disable #`. `#` Being the ID of the touchpad in `xinput` command. I disable the touchpad on my laptops because it seems no matter how much tweaking I do they always suck. Jittery and not accurate. Easier (and prefer) to just use a mouse.

Please help me to resolve it permanently. Thank you.

```
desktop@local:~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M325                             id=10  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=11  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7910-1023-12.00.00  id=13  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15  [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Comment: In Control Centre, under Mouse options there is a tab for the touch-pad, which includes the option to enable. Disabling this should remove all functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the X server to ignore it by writing your own `xorg.conf` file. Have a look at the `InputClass` section, keyword `Ignore`. See `man xorg.conf` for details.